# How do I use schemas within schemas when upgrading to Mongoose 4.x from Mongoose 3.x?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 files:

keyFeature:

```
mongoose = require('mongoose');

Schema = mongoose.Schema;

DescriptionSchema = require('./description');

KeyFeatureSchema = new Schema({
  descriptions: [DescriptionSchema],
  title: String,
  key: String,
  display: String,
  feature: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Module'
  }
});

module.exports = KeyFeatureSchema;
```

description:

```
mongoose = require('mongoose');

DescriptionSchema = new mongoose.Schema();

DescriptionSchema.add({
  display: String,
  subdescriptions: [String]
});

module.exports = DescriptionSchema;
```

How do I rewrite this to be compatible with Mongoose 4 `.add` syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but here is what I get.

According to the [mongoose .add documentation for 4.5.2](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-add) the add syntax still the same. So I have made a simple **testing.js** file with your schemas. I created a keyFeature object with one object inside descriptions array and saved it. After that, I connect to mongod using mongo console and query the **keyfeatures** collection. The object was properly inserted into db.

Here is my code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var DescriptionSchema = require('./description.js');
var KeyFeatureSchema = require('./keyFeature.js');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mongoose-testing', function(err)    {
    if(err){
        console.log('Could not connect to mongoose', err);
    }else{
        console.log('Successfully connected to mongoose');
        mongoose.model('Description', DescriptionSchema);
        mongoose.model('Keyfeature', KeyFeatureSchema);
        var Keyfeature = mongoose.model('Keyfeature');

        new Keyfeature({
            descriptions: [{
                display: 'This is the display content from descriptions',
                subdescriptions: ['Subdescription 1']
            }],
            title: 'tittle',
            key: 'key',
            display: 'display'
        }).save(function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log('Error when saving', err);
            }else{
                console.log('Saved');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Tested with **mongoose@4.5.2**